# Use Java to connect to a board with a microcontroller via ethernet

Tags: java

I had a board with a microcontroller(**PIC16F877A**) in it connected to the PC using LAN cable(**RJ45**).

I need to write the Java code to connect the board to the java application and get some data from the board. How can I do it?

Comment: you will need a lib like RxTxComm to handle that

Answer (score 0):

**PIC16F877A** has a serial port
 [image]
you will need a RS232 for the PIC and on the pc a java application, for the java part you can use the [RxTxComm library](http://www.jcontrol.org/download/readme_rxtx_de.html) 
some guy handle to do a handshake [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10257790/982161)